# Python function for getting locator values

Tags: python, xml, parsing, user-interface

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<uimap>
    <page name="login">
        <uielement name="username">
             <locator>//input[@type='text']</locator>           
        </uielement>
        <uielement name="password">
            <locator>//input[@type='password']</locator>
```

If I have an XML file like above, what I am trying to get to is, if I did:

`login.getlocator("username")`, where `login` is an object of XML section and `username`, is an attribute of the XML section. `getlocator` is just a function name that i am probably going to have to write.

The objective is, I want the value of the locator (I mean the text contained in login). Any suggestions on how I can get this going? I looked up `BeautifulSoup` which uses Python for XML parsing but are there any other options?

Comment: There is Python standard [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). Then [lxml](http://lxml.de/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de) and dynamically construct an xpath expression:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<uimap>
    <page name="login">
        <uielement name="username">
             <locator>//input[@type='text']</locator>
        </uielement>
        <uielement name="password">
            <locator>//input[@type='password']</locator>
        </uielement>
    </page>
</uimap>
"""

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
page = 'login'
element = 'username'

print tree.findtext('.//page[@name="{page}"]/uielement[@name="{element}"]/locator'.format(page=page, element=element))
```

Prints:

```
//input[@type='text']
```

---

Then, you can improve it and extract into a reusable function, like:

```
def get_locator(tree, page, element):
    return tree.findtext('.//page[@name="{page}"]/uielement[@name="{element}"]/locator'.format(page=page, element=element), 'Not Found')

tree = ET.fromstring(data)

print get_locator(tree, 'login', 'username')
print get_locator(tree, 'login', 'password')
print get_locator(tree, 'login', 'invalid element')
```

Prints:

```
//input[@type='text']
//input[@type='password']
Not Found
```

Of course, this still can be improved, but I hope it at least gives you a basic idea.

Comment: Alecxe: I want the username of that login. Like had i entered "johndoe" as the username, I should get "johndoe" as the output.

Comment: @user2921139 ok, could you provide an example input and desired output? What value is on the input and what should be in the output? Thanks.

Comment: Alece: I am sorry, I just need the locator value "//@..." as the output.

Comment: @user2921139 sorry, you need not just the `//input[@type='text']`, but `@type` from it? Other than that, is the answer helping? Thanks.

Comment: Alecxe - I wanted to try out what you gave me and I land on Cleaning up...
Command /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_user/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-FHRyQv-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_user/lxml

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip2.7", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip2.7')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 87: ordinal not in range(128)
[user@user tests]$

Comment: from lxml import etree as ET¬ 
fopen = open("ElementMap.xml", "r")¬
tree = ET.fromstring(fopen) I get an error on doing this which says ValueError: can only parse strings                                                                               
~

Comment: The difference I notice is: in your "data", the XML file is as is with indentation, whereas in my version "fopen" has a lot of crap in it. How can i read the XML file as is into a variable?

Comment: Alecxe- my XML file had some meta data messed up which is why all the confusion. XML issue is fixed. In the above function, will the "gettext..." always remain the same?? Will any locator use the same format?

Comment: @user2921139 sounds like yes, if I'm on the same page. Let me know if you still trying to make this work. Thanks.